# Function Loop in string too long

Tags: haskell, hugs

i have these functions:

```
item :: Parser Char
item  = Parser i
        where i []     = []
              i (x:xs) = [(x,xs)] 

many  :: Eq a=> Parser a -> Parser [a]
many p = many1 p +++ return []

many1  :: Eq a=> Parser a -> Parser [a]
many1 p = do v  <- p
             vs <- many p
             returns (v:vs)
```

Im getting strange results applying differents strings. If i execute:

```
parse (many item) "x:=0"
```

i get

```
[('x',0)]
```

while if i use another string longer like "if x=0 then x:=0 else x:=1" it looks like go in loop. Doing some attempts it seems that if the string is longer more than 19 chars the function doesnt end. It's strange because on other string long less 19 chars it works good. What it could be?

Other definitions:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }


instance Monad Parser where
    return t = Parser $ \s -> [(t, s)]
    m >>= k  = Parser $ \s -> [(x, y) | (u, v) <- parse m s, (x, y) <- parse (k u) v]

(+++) :: Eq a => Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = Parser $ \s -> if((parse p s)==[]) then parse q s else parse p s
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `many` and `many1` probably don't need the `Eq a` constraint. Related to your problem: what are the definitions of `Parser`, `parse`, `items`, `(+++)`, `returns`, and `(>>=)`?

Comment: @DanielWagner updated, it was item not items , wrong sorry

Comment: You should get rid of the `Eq` constraint in `(+++)` and use `null :: [a] -> Bool` or a `case` expression instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `(+++)` doesn’t do what you think it does. In particular, it will only return successful parsed from one of its arguments, rather than from both. Here is how to do what you want:

```
(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = Parser $ \s -> parse p s ++ parse q s
```

Although this doesn’t remove duplicates so be warned that you can end up with an explosion of parses by doing eg `many (many item)`.

Comment: yes it works, but i have a lot of duplicates as u said

Comment: One solution could be to only have `(+++)` work for `Parser a` when `Ord a`, and use sets to remove duplicates. But this would involve comparing strings over their length when actually you only need to compare them physically (ie strings are equal iff they are in the same memory location, but as things can move this type of equality can’t become an order). Another thing to consider would be changing the type of parse to return indexes instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, it's just that you've written your parser to have infinite backtracking and therefore `O(2^n)` runtime. Every character you add doubles the time it takes to complete:

```
$ time hugs foo.hs <<< 'parse (many item) "if x=0 then x:=0 els"'
[...]
Main> [("if x=0 then x:=0 els","")]
Main> [Leaving Hugs]

real    0m11.076s
user    0m10.578s
sys     0m0.016s
```

vs

```
$ time hugs foo.hs <<< 'parse (many item) "if x=0 then x:=0 else"'
[...]
Main> [("if x=0 then x:=0 else","")]
Main> [Leaving Hugs]

real    0m22.346s
user    0m22.048s
sys     0m0.036s
```